# How to evaluate a variable inside a variable bash scripting?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, bsd

I have a bunch of arrays like this:

```
array1=("A" "B")
array2=("C" "D")
array3=("E" "F" "G")
```

And I want to loop over the arrays, and the elements in each.  Here is how I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
for i in `seq 1 2`
do 
    for elm in ${array${i}[@]}
    do
        echo "the element in array$i is $elm" 
    done
done
```

But, this gives me:

```
./new_test.sh: line 6: ${array${i}[@]}: bad substitution
```

I sort of know that what I'm doing is wrong, because I don't want the first `$` to evaluate the `${i}` inside of it.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
var=array$i[@]
for elm in ${!var}
...
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=("A" "B")
array2=("C" "D")
array3=("E" "F" "G")

for i in `seq 1 2`
do 
    var=array$i[@]
    for elm in "${!var}"
    do
        echo "the element in array$i is $elm" 
    done
done
```

Output:

```
the element in array1 is A
the element in array1 is B
the element in array2 is C
the element in array2 is D
```

---

[Indirect expansion (from bash manual):](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as ***indirect expansion***. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Comment: Nice, but it seems the op is trying to avoid `var=array$i[@]`

Comment: @sjsam : I don't see any proof of that statement anywhere... expanding `${array${i}[@]}` to `${array1[@]}` is exactly what OP wants...

Comment: You should quote the expansion: `"${!var}"`

Comment: You could use: ``for var in $(seq -f 'array%.0f[@]' 1 2); do for elm in "${!var}"; do echo "the element in $var is $elm"; done; done`` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And since its bash: `for var in "array"{1..2}"[@]"; do ...`

Comment: Thanks.  So, is this called "indirect expansion"?  Still struggling a bit to understand when it is necessary to use the `!`, and when it is not necessary.

Comment: Also, @andlrc, what do you mean "*since its bash*"?  thanks.

Comment: The way I understand it `${!var}` is almost like `${${${b}}}`, if that were syntactically possible.

Comment: @buzzinolops : yes, it's known as `indirect expansion`, added relevant manual doc...

Comment: @buzzinolops Bash have brace expansion but POSIX doesn't: `echo "hello"{1..5}` will print `hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4 hello5` in bash but `hello{1..5}` in POSIX

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=("A" "B")
array2=("C" "D")
array3=("E" "F" "G")

for i in "array"{1..3}"[@]"; do
    echo "$i"
    for el in "${!i}"; do
        echo "$el"
    done
done
```

Output is:

```
array1[@]
A
B
array2[@]
C
D
array3[@]
E
F
G
```